# Sencha Touch with PhoneGap and LineaPro SDK

Tags: plugins, sdk, cordova, sencha-touch

I am building a `sencha` touch app integrated with `phonegap` and I have to implement a barcode scanner.

I bought a `LineaPro 4` (an external bar code scanner for ipod 4) and I downloaded the SDK.

Well, can someone explain me if it possible to integrate the `SDK` with my `sencha` touch app and suggest me a tutorial?